# Jira query that returns all projects that have issue-link dependencies that display the linked-from and linked-to project name

Tags: jira, jql

Need to come up with a Jira query that returns all projects that have issue-link dependencies, that display the linked-from and linked-to project name

Answer (score 0):

Jira cannot search for projects, it can search for issue only. However, you can put such search onto a dashboard, to Issue Statistics gadget and display the search result grouped by project.

Moreover, this cannot be searched by default JQL functions. You will need extra add-on to conduct such search. The best is [ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview).

You can then conduct such search:
`issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("project = XXX", "linked-to")`
or vice-versa:
`issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("project = XXX", "linked-from")`

The first argument is a subquery of all issues you're interested in. The query will return all issues linked with that respective link type with subquery issues.

ScriptRunner JQL function documentation:

- https://docs.adaptavist.com/sr4js/latest/features/jql-functions/included-jql-functions/issue-links#id-.IssueLinksv6.47.0-linkedissuesof